# Can't tell what is the error

Tags: moderncv

```
\makecvtitle

\section{Education}
\cventry{2011--2014}{Computer science engineering diploma}{Faculty of sciences-Elmanar}{Tunis}{\textit{}}{}
\cventry{2008--2011}{bachelor degree in sciences and technologies of information and communication}{Faculty of sciences-Elmanar}{Tunis}{\textit{}}{major in electronics and signals transmission with honours }
\cventry{2008}{bachelor}{khemir High school}{Aindrahem}{\textit{}}{major in Maths with honours}

\section{Experience}
\subsection{Vocational}
\cventry{July-August 2013}{Internship}{Ngtrend}{Tunis}{}{building and testing an MMS sending/receiving platform with Mbuni(gateway Open Source) and Nokia mms developer's suite}
\cventry{March 2013}{Realtime Translator}{Nomad, Forum Social Mondial}{Tunis}{}{using raspberry pi cards along with FM transmitters to set realtime translators during the "World Social Forum 2013"}
\cventry{June 2011}{Internship}{Tunisie Telecom}{Tunis}{}{developing a platform to send bulk sms.}
\subsection{Pedagogical}
\cventry{2013--2014}{Quadcopter project}{Tunis}{operating an arduino duemilanove card to build a quadcopter and control it with an android tablet (currently)}
\cventry{April 2013}{databases}{Tunis}{designing and building an appliction to manage students candidacies in our faculty using oracle forms}
\cventry{December 2013}{Embedded linux}{Tunis}{building a linux system on a raspberry pi}

\section{Computer skills}
\cvitem{programming langages}{C,C++,java,JEE,VHDL,Prolog,Assembly,Html,PHP}
\cvitem{IDE}{Netbeans,Altuim Designer,Isis,IAR,Arduino,Xilinx,Matlab,Eclipse,Oracle}
\cvitem{OS's}{Redhat(Fedora),Debian(Ubuntu,Mint),Backtrack,Windows}
\cvitem{Servers}{Tomcat,Apache,Mysql server}
\cvitem{Networks}{LANs,CISCO,signals transmission}

\section{Activities}
\cvitem{IEEE}{active member in IEEE FST student branch 2013}
\cvitem{Microdesign club}{active member in the embedded systems' club Microdesign}
\cvitem{CertifFST}{active member in the certification club CertifFST}
\cvitem{CTunis Extended, Forum Social Mondial}{streaming and enlarging orgnizations'activities during the World Social Forum 2013}
\cvitem{IEEE, RobotComp'2013}{participation in an annual robotics competition organized by IEEE}

\section{Languages}
\cvitem {English}{fluent}
\cvitem {French}{bilingual}
\cvitem {Arabic}{native}
\cvitem {Italian}{Basics}

\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{publications}                        % 'publications' is the name of a BibTeX file

\clearpage

%\clearpage\end{CJK*}                              % if you are typesetting your resume in Chinese using CJK; the \clearpage is required for fancyhdr to work correctly with CJK, though it kills the page numbering by making \lastpage undefined
\end{document}
```

I get this error

> ! Argument of \cventry has an extra }.\par \cventry{April 2013}

and this

> ! Paragraph ended before \cventry was complete.\par \cventry{April 2013}

and this

> ! Misplaced \cr. \cr \cventry{April 2013}

All at the same line!! what can be the error?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Every `\cventry` command *must* be followed by five braced groups. In `\cventry{2013--2014}` one you have only four (and the same in the following one). Check all of them.

Answer (score 2):

The `\cventry` command requires *five* braced arguments and you have only four of them in the line

```
\cventry{2013--2014}{Quadcopter project}{Tunis}{operating an arduino duemilanove card to build a quadcopter and control it with an android tablet (currently)}
```

that I rewrite with each argument in a separate line, which is legal syntax and probably preferable for checking the exact number of arguments:

```
\cventry{2013--2014}
  {Quadcopter project}
  {Tunis}
  {operating an arduino duemilanove card to build a quadcopter and control it with an android tablet (currently)}
```

What happens is that TeX wants five arguments, so it considers the following `\cventry` token as the fifth argument: chaos ensues. If you have nothing in the fifth argument, just specify an empty pair of braces.

```
\cventry{2013--2014}
  {Quadcopter project}
  {Tunis}
  {operating an arduino duemilanove card to build a quadcopter and control it with an android tablet (currently)}
  {}
```